# How to only let your character jump once?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a game where my character jumps from piece of land to land, problem is as long as the user taps the screen he will keep jumping up.

```
Knight.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
Knight.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 275))
```

This is what I have under touchesBegan that allows him to jump in the first place, how do I make it so once he makes contact with an SKSprite node it only allows him to jump once? 
The character can jump whenever the screen is tapped, but I want him to only be able to jump when he is on the ground and then the user taps the screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: How to make my character in my game only be able to jump once he hits the ground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290346/swift-how-to-make-my-character-in-my-game-only-be-able-to-jump-once-he-hits-the)

Comment: Please add this information (character can jump whenever the screen is tapped, not just once) to your earlier question, as they are very closely related.

Comment: @SteveIves I updated the question

Comment: Very tempted to down vote, as this is a duplicate of your other question.  I don't see a difference, and you got the same answer for both questions.

Answer (score 3):

We will use a counter. So every time you hit a platform, add, every time you leave, subtract. When your counter is 0, you are not on land.

Create an enum for BodyTypes somewhere ... I put it right above my GameScene class.

```
enum BodyType:UInt32 {
    case player = 1
    case platform = 2
}
```

set up your knight class as such...

```
class Knight: SKSpriteNode {
 // this variable will be toggled by didBegin Contact ... when 0 you are not land. Assumes that player starts on land. //
var onLandCounter = 1  

  func setUpKnight() { 
          /// call this in didMoveToView when setting up your nodes
          /// Should have other stuff in here too .. but this is the important bit //
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue

        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.platform.rawValue 

        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.platform.rawValue


  }

   func jump() {
         if (onLandCounter >= 1) {

             self.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
             self.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 275))
         }
       }
}
```

in touchesBegan you will instead do

```
theKnight.jump()
```

Note that assumes you created an instance of the Knight class and called it theKnight

the trick then is that you need a Platform class that you will custom class your ground bodies as e.g.

[image]

```
    class Platform: SKSpriteNode {
        func setUpPlatform() {

            self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.platform.rawValue
            self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue | BodyType.platform.rawValue
            self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue

        }
   }
```

Then use didBeginContact to cause the counter to change on your theKnight instance and allow jumping to once again occur because the knight has touched the ground. We add and the counter is now at least 1 , so we can jump.

e.g.

```
@objc(didBeginContact:) func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

            let firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
            let secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

            if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
                firstBody = contact.bodyA
                secondBody = contact.bodyB
            } else {
                firstBody = contact.bodyB
                secondBody = contact.bodyA
            }

            //MARK:  KNIGHT with PLATFORM

            if ( firstBody.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue && secondBody.categoryBitMask == BodyType.platformSurface.rawValue) {


                if let theKnight:Knight = firstBody.node as? Knight,
                let thePlatform:Platform = secondBody.node as? Platform
                {
                   theKnight.onLandCounter  += 1
                }

            }
    }
```

Remember to set things up in your GameScene properly

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var theKnight: Knight = Knight()


   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*") {
            node, stop in

        if let thePlatform:Platform = node as? Platform {

                thePlatform.setUpPlatform()

        }
     }

     // MARK: SET UP PLAYER

    // Assumes you call your player in the Scene "Player1" 
    //AND! you set it's custom class to Knight 

        if (self.childNode(withName: "Player1") != nil) {

           theKnight = self.childNode(withName: "Player1") as! Knight


           theKnight.setUpKnight()       
     }
  }
}
```

LAST!!! In didEndContact

```
@objc(didEndContact:) func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

            let firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
            let secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

            if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
                firstBody = contact.bodyA
                secondBody = contact.bodyB
            } else {
                firstBody = contact.bodyB
                secondBody = contact.bodyA
            }

            //MARK:  KNIGHT with PLATFORM

            if ( firstBody.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue && secondBody.categoryBitMask == BodyType.platformSurface.rawValue) {


                if let theKnight:Knight = firstBody.node as? Knight,
                let thePlatform:Platform = secondBody.node as? Platform
                {
                   theKnight.onLand -= 1
                }

            }
    }
```

Don't forget to custom class your knight!

[image]

Now you have a set up... where the jump function is only turned on when your player makes contact with a "ground" node.

Adjust this solution to however it fits your own code. Let me know if I forgot a brace or something.

The point is.... is that you are just using a counter to prevent the jump function from being used.

Comment: Your knight can jump if he falls off a platform

Comment: The person gave you the answer in the duplicate thread. I just went into more detail and gave examples with code. My answer is literally parallel to the idea of: "You may track collision with land with a boolean and set it false after a jump occured. – the4kman".

Comment: I updated my solution to be exactly like that one. You take my basic idea and include a didEndContact part.

Comment: Edit your answer to reflect that, otherwise your answer is bugged

Comment: Now all you need is to help him solve the problem of leaving a platform and entering another

Comment: Basically, enter platform2 followed by leave platform1 disables jump

Comment: This, I will give you a hand with.  Instead of running a boolean, use a counter.  Every time you hit a platform, add, every time you leave, subtract.  When your counter is 0, you are not on land.

Comment: Yup,  got to love how simple solutions turn into complex problems right? lol

Comment: Yes, 2 platforms physically next to each other side by side, no gap inbetween

Comment: But, his question says he jumps from piece of land to piece of land. If he's doing two different platform nodes side by side it changes the question.

Comment: always try to develop for future problems, will save you a lot of time when attempting to refactor old code.  There is no reason why a piece of land could not consist of multiple platform bodies (Image a flat platform followed by an angled platform,  you want to treat this as 1 solid piece of land, but 2 platforms)

Comment: I'm tempted to resist the counter solution. In the sake of developing for future problems... Sometimes I find didBeginContact / didEndContact is called multiple times... since your character may contact on two different parts. So that might screw up the counter. E.g. You hit the platform and it calls didBeginContact X2 and your counter is messed up. Instead maybe for adjacent nodes... I would subclass and create an AdjacentPlatform class. The subclass would have a different BodyType. So you'd lay things out Platform - AdjacentPlatform-Platform

Comment: If your didBeginContact fires twice, then your didEndContact will also fire twice.  Handling multiple contacts is a problem outside of this questions scope

Comment: didBeginContact fires twice because 2 different points have made contact with another body.  This is not a bug, and should be handled accordingly. (In most cases, you just need a flag saying a contact has happened, ignore future contacts,  I like using categoryBitMask bit 30 for this)

Comment: I updated my solution since your right and the counter makes sense. Let me know if it's still wrong. Feel free to edit it, if I missed something. Note: Is there a question that deals with setting a flag to ignoring future contact? I'd like to see that in example form if possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082179/swift-error-in-didbegincontact-if-running-newer-iphone-in-simulator/39082656#39082656  This has to deal with death, but can be applied in the same fashion

Comment: How could the counter be more than 1? Isn't it always 1 or 0?

Comment: nope. 1 or 0 means true or false,  Side by side platforms, what if my left foot is on platform 1, and my right foot is on platform 2.  I am now touching 2 platforms

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with checking touch location with node location ?
Get touch location from toughBegan:

```
  let point = touch.location(in: self)
```

if  there is a node at that point is equal to your object ,perform jump

```
 let nodes = self.nodes(at: point)
```

Comment: This won't help with the question at hand.